# If $C$ has measure zero and is in $[0,1]$ is $[0,1]\backslash$ $C$ dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Is it true that if $C$ has measure zero and is in $[0,1]$, then $[0,1]\backslash$ $C$ dense in $[0,1]$ for any general $C\subset [0,1]$?

If not, what are some counterexamples?

Comment: yes, its true.,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that the complement of zero-measure set on $[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282598/proof-that-the-complement-of-zero-measure-set-on-0-1-is-dense-in-0-1)

Answer (score 2):

This is true. For $[0,1] \backslash C$ to be dense in $[0,1]$ there would have to be an element of it in every non empty open subset of $[0,1]$. We could argue by contraposition. If $[0,1] \backslash C$ was not dense in $[0,1]$ then we could find a non empty open subset of $[0,1]$ that is disjoint with $[0,1] \backslash C$. However that means that this open subset is a subset of $C$ and since any non empty open subset of $[0,1]$ does not have measure zero that would mean that $C$ does not have measure zero.