# Proof that if the measure of the complement of A is 0, then A is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $m(A^c) = 0$, then $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Any thoughts? What have you done? It is not good practice to simply post the statement of your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that the complement of zero-measure set on $[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282598/proof-that-the-complement-of-zero-measure-set-on-0-1-is-dense-in-0-1)

Comment: Open balls have positive volume.

Answer (score 3):

We have to use that a set $B$ with zero outer measure is Lebesgue measurable, which implies that $B^\mathsf c$ is Lebesgue measurable too;  we'll also use the monotonicity of the Lebesgue measure, i.e., if there are two measurable sets $B\subset C$ then $m(B)\le m(C)$; and that a nonempty open ball $B$ has positive measure (and it's Lebesgue measurable of course), since it contains a non-degenerated interval, which has positive measure.

If $U$ is open and nonempty and $A\cap U=\emptyset$ then $U\subset A^\mathsf c$, so $m(U)\le m(A^\mathsf c)=0$, and thus $m(U)=0$.

However, since $U$ is open and nonempty, for $x\in U$ there is some $r$ such that $B(x,r)\subset U$, so $0<m(B(x,r))\le m(U)$, which is clearly a contradiction.

Therefore $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$, and $A$ must be dense.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: in the second paragraph it must be $m(U) = 0$ not $m(A) = 0$.

Comment: You're right! Duly corrected; thanks!