# What is wrong with the following proof that $\{ (\frac{3}{2})^n\mod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \} $ is dense in $\ [0,1]\ $?

Tags: solution-verification, open-problem, equidistribution

What is wrong with the following straightforward proof that $\ \lbrace{ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \mod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace}\ $ is dense in $\ [0,1]\ $ ?

In fact, let $\ f(x) = \lbrace{\ x^n \mod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace}.\ $ Then the following proves that $\ f(x)\ $ is dense in $\ [0,1]\ $ for all $\ x>1,\ x\notin \mathbb{N}.\ $ However, I will show my  attempted proof for $\ x=\frac{3}{2}\ $ and then you can just replace $\ \frac{3}{2}\ $ with any $\ x>1,\ x\notin \mathbb{N}, $ throughout.

Firstly, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Complete_uniform_distribution) suggests that $\ (\alpha \mod 1 ,\alpha ^{2} \mod 1,\alpha ^{3} \mod 1,\dots )\ $ is uniformly distributed for all $\ \alpha >1\ $ except for a set of measure $0.$  Let $\ Y\ $ be the set of all $\ \alpha>1\ $ such that $\ (\alpha \mod 1 ,\alpha ^{2} \mod 1,\alpha ^{3} \mod 1,\dots )\ $ is uniformly distributed.  Then $Y\cap[1,2]\ $ [must be dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282598/proof-that-the-complement-of-zero-measure-set-on-0-1-is-dense-in-0-1) in $[1,2].$

Therefore, there are (we can choose) two sequences, $\ a_n\subset Y\ $ and $\ b_n\subset Y\ $, such that $a_n\to\frac{3}{2}^-\ $ and $\ b_n\to\frac{3}{2}^+.$ From what wikipedia says about the set $Y$, $\ f(a_n)\ $ and $f(b_n)\ $ are dense subsets of $[0,1]\ $ for every $\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Fix $\ \gamma \in (0,1)\ $ and let $ \delta\ $ be any number with $ \ 0<\delta<\min\{\gamma, 1-\gamma \},\ $ and $\ \delta\ $ can be as small as you like.

Then there exist $\ n_1,\ n_2,\ m,\ N,\ $ such that

$$ N +\gamma -\delta < {a_{n_1}}^m < N + \gamma < {b_{n_2}}^m < N + \gamma + \delta.\quad (1)$$

Since $\ \frac{3}{2}\ $ is sandwiched between $\ a_{n_1}\ $ and $\ b_{n_2},\ $ we must also have that

$$N+\gamma-\delta < \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^m < N+\gamma + \delta.\quad (2)$$

Since $\ \delta\ $ was arbitrary, we can always find $\ N,\ m\ $ so that $\ (2)\ $ holds. This completes the proof.

---

Note: I didn't prove $\ (1)\ $ because it seems elementary and would distract from the overall proof. However, I can provide a proof if anyone isn't sure or requests it. But for example, the real function $\ g(x) = x^n\ $ is continuous, so that ought to do it [and this "continuity" proof highlights that the proof won't work for $\ x\in \mathbb{N}.$]

Anyway, my attempt to answer my own question is that either Wikipedia is wrong in it's claim, or I misunderstand Wikipedia's claim. Basically my logic is this: Wikipedia claims that the sequence $ (\alpha\mod 1 ,\alpha ^{2}\mod 1,\alpha ^{3}\mod 1,\dots )$ is completely uniformly distributed for all $\ \alpha >1\ $ except for a set of measure $0$, which implies that it is $k-uniformly$ distributed for each natural number $k\geq 1$ which implies it is $1-uniformly$ distributed, which is the same as saying it is uniformly distributed...

Comment: I think $(1)$ is where you got it wrongly. How can you ensure $N$ is the same? I think natural numbers satisfying $N + \gamma - \delta < {a_{n}}^m < N + \gamma$ for fixed $\gamma, \delta$ are rather rare (e.g. have density $0$).

Comment: Well, the proof can’t work for all non-integer $x>1.$ For example, $x=2+\sqrt{3}$ has $(x^n\bmod 1)\to1$ as $n\to\infty.$ You can see that because $(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n$ is always an integer, and $0<2-\sqrt3<1.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't think so. You may never find such $N$. The integer parts of $a_{m}^{p}$ and $b_{n}^{q}$ grow exponentially and it is unlikely that these $2$ sequences lie in the same unit interval for infinite times! Just like the [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) in number theory.

Comment: @Zerox I think you are right that $(1)$ is unjustified. But I think I can amend $(1)$ somehow to make it correct (at least, I'm going to give it a try). I might be wrong, but trying and failing is how we learn, right?

Comment: This proof is definitely wrong as all Pisot numbers raised to integer powers mod 1 converge to a periodic sequence. That is, for $x$ a Pisot number, the sequence mod$(x^n,1)$ converges to a periodic sequence. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes you are right, and so is QC_QAOA. But I was wondering where in my proof I went wrong. I think Zerox pointed this out correctly. I am now trying to salvage my proof, but I can see now that I probably won't be able to, for the reason Zerox gives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Zerox, $\ (1),\ $

> There exist $\ n_1,\ n_2,\ m,\ N,\ $ such that
> $ N +\gamma -\delta < {a_{n_1}}^m < N + \gamma < {b_{n_2}}^m < N +
> \gamma + \delta.\quad (1)$

has not been justified.

My idea when writing the proof attempt was that for any $\ \delta>0,\ $ no matter how small, $\ \exists\ \varepsilon>0, m,N\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ y\in \left(\frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon, \frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon\right) \implies  N +\gamma -\delta < \left(\frac{3}{2}-\varepsilon\right)^m\ < N+\gamma < \left(\frac{3}{2} +\varepsilon\right)^m\ < N +\gamma +\delta. $

However, this only makes sense if we assume that $\ \lbrace{ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n \mod 1: n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace}\ $ is dense in $\ [0,1],\ $ which is the result we are trying to prove. [I think I did this without realising it was what I was doing].

I have tried to salvage $(1)$ but I don't see a way to do this.