# $\lambda (S^c) = 0 \implies \overline{S} = \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure. Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(S^c) = 0$. Can we conclude that $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}?$

This fact was used by my professor when solving a problem, but I can't find this in the literature nor prove it myself.

Comment: Suppose $S$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$, i.e. $\exists x\in \mathbb R,\exists \varepsilon >0: (x-\varepsilon ,x+\varepsilon )\cap S=\emptyset$. Therefore, $\lambda (S^c)\geq 2\varepsilon $ which contradict $\lambda (S^c)=0$.

Comment: Try to adapt the proof in this question: [Proof that the complement of zero-measure set on $[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282598/proof-that-the-complement-of-zero-measure-set-on-0-1-is-dense-in-0-1).